# How to include Webpack build plugin

Tags: javascript, gulp, webpack

I created a project without webpack. Now just for learning webpack, I am including in my project.

I have a following files which I am trying to build through webpack:

#### main.js

```
define(['../libs/nunjucks.slim.js'], function(nunjucks){
      // use the nunjucks variable
});
```

#### nunjucks.slim.js

> [Link](https://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/files/nunjucks-slim.js) (*Webpack build plugin*)

But `main.js` is throwing error - `nunjucks is not defined`. I don't know what I am doing wrong here.

As per my understanding, in `nunjucks.slim.js` file, if I replace `var nunjucks` to `window.nunjucks` it works fine. But I am not intending to have global variables. and this is already a webpack build plugin, it will be meaningless if I do `module.exports = nunjucks`.

Please suggest what should I do here?

BTW, I am using `gulp-webpack` and here is the code in `gulpfile.js`:

```
function moduleLoader(){
    return gulp.src('scripts/**/*.js')
        .pipe(webpack({
            entry:{
                main: './scripts/js/main.js'
            },
            output:{
                filename: '[name].js'
            }
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('site/assets/js/'));
}

function watchChanges(){
    moduleLoader();
    gulp.watch([
        'scripts/**/*.js'
    ], [
        'webpack:build'
    ]);
}

gulp.task('webpack:build', moduleLoader);
gulp.task('watch', watchChanges);
```